# Date() returns hour over 24

Tags: ios, swift, date

I have to send date from my iPhone through my app to server, but I was surprised that the date had stored as NULL (not always) in server, that's the code used for that:

```
timeS = (Date().millisecondsSince1970)
// make some assertions on timeS
let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timeS)
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale.current
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
return dateString
```

It seems like the c# code in the server side tried to convert the string to date and it failed, so it was stored NULL.

So recently I tried to send the date without any modifications in a string to see what happened:

```
self.backS.sendLocation(msg: "data fitched \(Date())")
```

and that's what I found in the database:

> data fitched 2018-05-08 **77**:45:44 AM +0000

it must be:

> data fitched 2018-05-08 **07**:45:44 AM +0000 (because that was the time for the server)

I don't know why is that happened!!

I really appreciate anybody's help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get your current date and time like this in Swift.

```
let date = Date()
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"
let result = formatter.string(from: date)
self.backS.sendLocation(msg: "data fetched \(result)")
```

Your result will be like this.

```
"2018-05-12 14:34:51 +0000"
```

Comment: that's what I did for the date column, I didn't know why it received as null until I put the date without any format or anything in the "msg" field.

Comment: I tried your solution, the result was like this:
"2018-05-12 14:02:20 +0300"
I want it "+0000" not "+0300",
 I edited my question to be more clear, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To send the date to server you should rather use Unix timestamp, instead of date in string format.

But, if you insist on a string, you should use `DateFormatter`. When using `DateFormatter` you should always set the `locale` property of your formatter. That ensures the formateer will return consistens results, regardless of your phone's regional settings.

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"
let dateString = formatter.string(from: Date())
```

It's important to set the `locale` property before you set the `dateFormat` property.

If you don't set the `locale` property, the formatter might return `nil` when working with 24-format on devices with 12-hour format set, and vice versa.

Source: [Technical Q&A QA1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1480/_index.html)

Comment: Could you please explain why anybody should use Unix timestamps?

Comment: Also, since you are quoting `QA1480`, you should also set the time zone on the formatter.

Comment: @Sulthan Unix timestamps are independent of time zone, so they are a good choice for distributed client-server applicatins. As for time zone, the one set in device's regional settings should be used (hence not setting this property). Setting `locale` property is necessary, because using 24-hour format on device with 12-hour format set may result in receiving `nil` as return value for `string(for:)` method - which seems to be the case, based on op's comment to @Rizwan Ahmed's answer.

Comment: Great find @mag_zbc

Comment: The date it self wasn't returned as NULL, but after failure in conversion it stored as NULL.
I edited my question to be more clear, Thanks.

Comment: @mag_zbc ISO date strings are also independent on time zone. Every time you specify a time zone, the string is safe to use. There is nothing better about unix timestamps and they are less readable.

Comment: @mag_zbc Setting time zone is needed when parsing. Otherwise the predefined time zone is used, including all DST changes, non-existent times, time-shifts depending on that time zone etc. You need to set the time zone when parsing in the same way you have to set the locale.